# ¿Cómo empezar con Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, component

He estado checando un poco por encima arquitectura en la pagina oficial " https://angular.io/guide/architecture " pero no me quedan claro como funciona. Tengo un poco de expereriencia con Java, javascript y C, y sé que si vienes de javacript se facilita Angular, pero estoy confundido. Un consejo, video, curso que me puedan recomendar

Comment: Bienvenido. En este sitio las preguntas deben ser sobre problemas específicos. Así como está tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y principalmente basada en opiniones. Sería bueno que hicieras el [tour], leyeras [ask] y replatearas tu pregunta sobre algo en particular que te causa confusión.

Comment: Okay, gracias, lo voy a hacer

Comment: Mi consejo es que te leas esa documentación que indicas y que hagas el ejemplo de Tour of heores (https://angular.io/tutorial)

Comment: Además, en udemy (https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?ref=home&src=ukw&q=angular%205) tienes tutoriales baratos en castellano y si quieres gastarte algo más de dinero (aunque muy bien invertido) te recomiendo los tutoriales de Todd Motto (UltimateAngular > https://ultimateangular.com/). Están en inglés sin subtítulos pero se le entiende muy bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin duda lo mejor para empezar con Angular es usar Angular-CLI.

Lo primero para empezar con angular es saber que tenemos entre manos, así que veo fundamental hacer un recorrido sobre algunos puntos claves en formato `humano entendible`.

**Qué es Angular ?**

Angular es un framework javascript creado por Google basado en componentes que nos permite crear aplicaciones web SP(single pages). Cuando decimos esto nos referimos a la interfaz gráfica de la app, ya que si dicha aplicación necesita persistencia de datos por ejemplo, angular no nos soluciona la parte del `BackEnd`, teniendo así que desarrollar otra app tipo API-REST, escrita en PHP, JAVA, JAVASCRIPT(Nodejs), C# ... tu lenguage de servidor favorito.

**Por qué Typescript?** **[Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)**

Angular al igual que Jquery no deja de ser javascript, por lo que alfinal de todo tendremos que tener un archivo html (index.html) donde usemos una bonita etiqueta `script` o varias.

Aquí nos preguntamos y que rol tiene Typescript en todo esto ?

Typescript es un superset de javascript que solo se ejecuta durante el desarrollo, esto solo quiere decir que es javascript pero con algunas caracteristicas interesantes como tipado y soporte a funcionalidades todavía no presente en los navegadores actuales.

Typescript se instala en nuestro ordenador y permite generar código javascript a partir de archivos con extensión `ts`. El código generado será el que incluiremos en las etiquetas `scripts`. Depende de su correcta configuración generar código compatible con los navegadores actuales.

Puedes jugar un poco con typescript en linea en el siguiente link oficial **[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)** , es un compilador en linea que typescript que ademas te permite ver la salida a javascript, es muy útil para enteder que hace exactamente typescript.

**Qué es Angular CLI? [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)**

Aunque se puede utilizar Angular sin Typescript, su uso es mas que recomendable. Para no hacer tan arduo configurar un proyecto completo de Angular con Typescript, el equipo de Angular creo la `Angular CLI`, una herramienta de consola interactiva que nos permite crear y modificar un proyecto angular desde cero, una especie de `Boilerplate`.

Esta herramienta necesita ser instalada con `npm` es decir el gestor de dependencias de Nodejs. Así que tendrás que instalar tambien NodeJs en tu ordenador.

Una vez instalada Angular-CLI solo con un simple comando `ng new` generaremos un proyecto de angular completo. Esto quiere decir que lo podriamos compilar y publicar en cualquier hosting web para probarlo.

**Resumen de herramientas para el desarrollo**

- NodeJs (incluye npm para instalar angular-cli)
- Linea de comandos (iterm, powershell, cmd ...)
- Angular CLI (creará la estructura del proyecto)
- Tu editor favorito (recomiendo **[Visual code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)**)

**Y ahora qué?**

Como te han comentado lo mejor sería reproducir el ejemplo oficial de angular **[Tour of heores](https://angular.io/tutorial)** que te dará una visión más detallada de un proyecto angular.

Creo que es suficiente como para cogerle ganas y empezar a hacer algo con angular y una vez a partir de esto cuando tengas dudas concretas postearlo con un ejemplo de código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Sin embargo, las preguntas basadas en opiniones son motivo de cierre. No todas las respuestas han de responderse porque aunque ayuden al usuario, no ayudan al sitio. Un saludo